# Base Class Constructor not being accessed in Derived Class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to learn C++ policy based design and wrote the following snippet, and I got the following error:

```
 class 'Binary_Tree<DataType, TreeNode, Traversal_Policy>' does not have any field named 'Tree_Base'
   90 |         Binary_Tree(DataType val,Traversal_Policy traversal_policy_type):Root(val),Tree_Base(traversal_policy_type){};
```

Not sure where I am making a mistake as Tree Base should be directly accessible from Binary_Tree

```
class Tree_Traversal_Policy
{
    public:
        enum traversal_type{PREFIX=0,INFIX,POSTFIX};
        Tree_Traversal_Policy(traversal_type type):m_traversal_type(type){};
    private:
        traversal_type m_traversal_type;
};
template <typename DataType,template <typename> typename TreeNode,typename Traversal_Policy=Tree_Traversal_Policy>
class Tree_Base:public Traversal_Policy
{
    public:
        Tree_Base(Traversal_Policy traversal_policy_type):Traversal_Policy(traversal_policy_type){};
};
template <typename DataType,template < typename > typename TreeNode,typename Traversal_Policy>
class Binary_Tree:public Tree_Base<DataType,TreeNode,Traversal_Policy>
{
    using BTreeNode_ = TreeNode <DataType>;
    BTreeNode_ Root;
    public:
        Binary_Tree(DataType val,Traversal_Policy traversal_policy_type):Root(val),Tree_Base(traversal_policy_type){};
        void add_node(DataType val);
        void delete_node(DataType val);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The ability to omit the template arguments from the use of an instantiated template class is limited to the body of the templated class itself. You can refer to `Tree_Base` simply as `Tree_Base` only in `Tree_Base`; in `Binary_Tree` and elsewhere you must qualify it with the template arguments. So:

```
Binary_Tree(DataType val,Traversal_Policy traversal_policy_type):
    Root(val),
    Tree_Base<DataType,TreeNode,Traversal_Policy>(traversal_policy_type) 
{};
```

Note that it's common to do something like `using Base = Tree_Base<DataType,TreeNode,Traversal_Policy>` in the class definition to avoid all that extra typing. If you do that, you can simply refer to it as `Base` in the initializer.

Comment: Thank You so much!, that resolved the error!

Comment: @UjjwalArora - You can also use `Binary_Tree::Tree_Base` instead of re-specifying or adding an alias. The tricky part of templates is that some things aren't dependent by default in hard to foresee way.